# Ignore Files when copying using scp

Tags: scp

How to ignore certain files when using the `scp` command?
I have the following file structure on the Linux server :

**Everything >**

- NeedThis
- NeedThisToo
- DontNeedThis

I want to get `NeedThis` and `NeedThisToo` and ignore `DontNeedThis`.
I can't just use two separate scps as in reality there are a few hundred files.

Neither can I move nor copy anything (part of this problem, can be seen as a set condition). Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

Comment: Would you be able to connect to the server with some other program that is easier to use with regards to excluding and including specific names and paths, such as `rsync`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `rsync` command in place of `scp` allows us to be more precise with what we want to exclude.  Assuming you want to do a recursive copy of some remote directory to a local directory but want to exclude a name from the operation:

```bash
rsync -av --exclude=DontNeedThis user@remote:/some/dir/ /some/dir
```

The above command would recursively copy the contents of the remote directory `/some/dir` into the local directory `/some/dir`, while avoiding anything named `DontNeedThis` (where `DontNeedThis` may be some quoted pattern).

Note that the final `/` on the source path is significant. Without it, you'd copy the directory, not its contents.

For a full explanation of the patterns that you may use to exclude or include things, see the section called "INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES" in the `rsync` manual.